# Logging into Azure DevOps services, I have three users, all the same, to select from — why?

Tags: azure-devops

After signing-in to Azure DevOps Services, on the left pane I can select from three different accounts:

[image: Azure DevOps Services launch screen]

All these accounts are pointing to my name and my e-mail address.

What's there reason I have three different accounts? How can I delete the redundant ones? Is there any documentation available, explaining this odd situation?

Comment: Those are the Azure tenants you are member/guest of.